# How to convert a date to milliseconds

Tags: java, date

I want to convert `String myDate = "2014/10/29 18:10:45"` to 
`long ms (i.e. currentinmlilies)`? I look for it on Google, but I can only find how to convert *ms* to *date*.

Note: To make it clear, I want to get the ms from the date in 1970/1/1 format.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is your friend.

Comment: How would you convert a date to milliseconds do you mean time?

Comment: Also you say ms to date?

Comment: Do you mean milliseconds since a certain point in time?

Comment: Yes, of course I mean time. It's not ms to date, it's date to ms.

Comment: **To all future readers**: use classes from `java.time`.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You don't have a `Date`, you have a `String` representation of a date. You should convert the `String` into a `Date` and then obtain the milliseconds. To convert a `String` into a `Date` and vice versa you should use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Here's an example of what you want/need to do (assuming time zone is not involved here):

```
String myDate = "2014/10/29 18:10:45";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
long millis = date.getTime();
```

Still, be careful because in Java the milliseconds obtained are the milliseconds between the desired epoch and 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

---

Using the new Date/Time API available since Java 8:

```
String myDate = "2014/10/29 18:10:45";
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(myDate,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") );
/*
  With this new Date/Time API, when using a date, you need to
  specify the Zone where the date/time will be used. For your case,
  seems that you want/need to use the default zone of your system.
  Check which zone you need to use for specific behaviour e.g.
  CET or America/Lima
*/
long millis = localDateTime
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: Caution: This Answer does not address the crucial issue of what time zone is being applied while parsing that input string.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque answer updated. I haven't noticed that you posted an answer as well.

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(           // Parse into an object representing a date with a time-of-day but without time zone and without offset-from-UTC.
    "2014/10/29 18:10:45"      // Convert input string to comply with standard ISO 8601 format.
    .replace( " " , "T" )      // Replace SPACE in the middle with a `T`.
    .replace( "/" , "-" )      // Replace SLASH in the middle with a `-`.
)
.atZone(                       // Apply a time zone to provide the context needed to determine an actual moment.
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Oslo" ) // Specify the time zone you are certain was intended for that input.
)                              // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toInstant()                   // Adjust into UTC.
.toEpochMilli()                // Get the number of milliseconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
```

> 1414602645000

## Time Zone

The accepted answer is correct, except that it ignores the **crucial issue of time zone**. Is your input string 6:10 PM in Paris or Montréal? Or [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)?

Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Usually a continent plus city/region. For example, `"Europe/Oslo"`. Avoid the 3 or 4 letter codes which are neither standardized nor unique.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Alter your input to conform with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. And replace the slash characters with hyphens. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2014/10/29 18:10:45".replace( " " , "T" ).replace( "/" , "-" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

A `LocalDateTime`, like your input string, lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Without the context of a zone/offset, a `LocalDateTime` has no real meaning. Is it 6:10 PM in India, Europe, or Canada? Each of those places experience 6:10 PM at different moments, at different points on the timeline. So you must specify which you have in mind if you want to determine a specific point on the timeline.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Oslo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now we have a specific moment, in that `ZonedDateTime`. Convert to UTC by extracting a `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Now we can get your desired count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Be aware of possible data loss. The `Instant` object is capable of carrying microseconds or nanoseconds, finer than milliseconds. That finer fractional part of a second will be ignored when getting a count of milliseconds.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

**Update:** The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. I will leave this section intact for history.

Below is the same kind of code but using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.5 library and handling time zone.

The java.util.Date, .Calendar, and .SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them. Use either Joda-Time or the java.time package (inspired by Joda-Time) built into Java 8.

## ISO 8601

Your string is almost in ISO 8601 format. The slashes need to be hyphens and the SPACE in middle should be replaced with a `T`. If we tweak that, then the resulting string can be fed directly into constructor without bothering to specify a formatter. Joda-Time uses ISO 8701 formats as it's defaults for parsing and generating strings.

## Example Code

```
String inputRaw = "2014/10/29 18:10:45";
String input = inputRaw.replace( "/", "-" ).replace( " ", "T" );
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Oslo" ); // Or DateTimeZone.UTC
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, zone );
long millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch = dateTime.getMillis();
```

Comment: Which DateTimeZone ID are it in Norway? It is something about GMT +1, I'm not sure.

Comment: *The accepted answer is correct, except that it ignores the crucial issue of time zone* I don't ignore it, I'm using the system default time zone. Java legacy date API uses it.

Answer (score 6):

The [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class allows you to parse a `String` into a `java.util.Date` object. Once you have the Date object, you can get the milliseconds since the epoch by calling `Date.getTime()`.

The full example:

```
String myDate = "2014/10/29 18:10:45";
//creates a formatter that parses the date in the given format
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
long timeInMillis = date.getTime();
```

Note that this gives you a `long` and not a double, but I think that's probably what you intended. The documentation for the `SimpleDateFormat` class has tons on information on how to set it up to parse different formats.

Answer (score 5):

The 2017 answer is: Use the date and time classes introduced in Java 8 (and also backported to Java 6 and 7 in the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)).

If you want to interpret the date-time string in the computer’s time zone:

```
    long millisSinceEpoch = LocalDateTime.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
```

If another time zone, fill that zone in instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. If UTC, use

```
    long millisSinceEpoch = LocalDateTime.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: LocalDateTime is not defined

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, @YASHDAVE. You need to import `LocalDateTime`. If you are using Java 8 or later, just use `import java.time.LocalDateTime`;. If Java 6 or 7, get the ThreeTen Backport I linked to in the answer and then use `import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve issue with using LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormatter

```
    String date = "21/04/2022 12:42:29";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    System.out.println(dt.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```