# How to know if a date is in previous x minutes?

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, simpledateformat

I have an ISO String date like this one: `2019-12-17 15:14:29.198Z`

I would like to know if this date is in the previous 15 minutes from now.
Is-it possible to do that with `SimpleDateFormat` ?

```
val dateIso = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.FRENCH).parse(isoString)
```

Comment: is the date in UTC?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/26637209/7074278

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: You might want to try using Android ThreeTen date libraries

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 4):

## `java.time.Instant`

Use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class to represent a moment in UTC.

To parse, replace SPACE with a `T` per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-12-17 15:14:29.198Z".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Determine the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Determine 15 minutes ago. Call `plus…`/`minus…` methods for date-time math.

```
Instant then = now.minusMinutes( 15 ) ;
```

Apply your test. Here we use the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
boolean isRecent = 
    ( ! instant.isBefore( then ) )  // "Not before" means "Is equal to or later".
    && 
    instant.isBefore( now )         
;
```

For older Android, add the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library that wraps the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library. Android 26+ bundles *java.time* classes.

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

If you are doing much of this work, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project (may not be appropriate for Android, not sure). This gives you the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class and it’s handy comparison methods such as [`contains`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html#contains(java.time.Instant)).

```
Interval.of( then , now ).contains( instant )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the reference date everytime you access the program, you can use java.util.Calendar.

```
boolean isBefore;
long timeToCheck = 15*60*1000; //15 minutes.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(), calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, yourDay);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, yourHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, yourMinute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, yourSecond);

if (calendar.before(calendar2)){
  long timeInMillis = calendar2.getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis();
  if ( timeInMillis >= timeToCheck ) isBefore = true;
  else isBefore = false;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score -1):

Is this you want:

```
int xMinutes = 10 * 60 * 1000;
long dateIsoinMillis = dateIso.getTime();
long xMinsAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - xMinutes;
if (dateIsoinMillis < xMinsAgo) {
    System.out.println("searchTimestamp is older than 10 minutes");
}
```